# What causes text to have an odd character at the end

Tags: django, font-awesome, bootstrap-5

I am using the django standard base.html  with the following

```
{% load i18n static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}{% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-us" }}" dir="{{ LANGUAGE_BIDI|yesno:'rtl,ltr,auto' }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5135d630a7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
```

This is giving me the following header with Home and Admin Pages having an odd character at the end. Is it the font?

[image]

[image]

I tried to get rid of the odd character and tried this...

```
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home .</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="/admin/">Admin Pages .</a>
                      </li>
```

And that got rid of the odd character but still not right as you can see below.

[image]

Edited...

Ok progress but no resolution.

I turned off the bg-dark and now see the source of the 'odd characters' each of the links in the nav-bar has a black box on the right side and that is what was mucking with the characters.  Searched for what those are and how to remove them but did not find it, probably  because I am not searching for the right term.

[image]

Comment: That's not an odd character.  That's the character you want, with a black square covering the upper left quadrant.  I would be suspicious of your CSS, but it would be hard to chase down.  Have you poked around using "Developer Tools"?

Comment: Yes I did but did inspect it but didn't see anything that jumped out at me.

Comment: Probably a bullet point pseudo element like `:marker`, `:before`, or `:after` - check you css for custom list styles.